# Storybook react native (IOS) - RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (native stack depth)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, storybook

For IOS - got this error while setting up storybook for current react native app in IOS .using RN 0.66.1 version, using "@storybook/react-native": "^5.3.25",

storybook/index.js -

```
// if you use expo remove this line
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

import { getStorybookUI, configure, addDecorator } from '@storybook/react-native';
import { withKnobs } from '@storybook/addon-knobs';

import './rn-addons';

// enables knobs for all stories
addDecorator(withKnobs);

// import stories
configure(() => {
  require('./stories');
}, module);

// Refer to https://github.com/storybookjs/react-native/tree/master/app/react-native#getstorybookui-options
// To find allowed options for getStorybookUI
const StorybookUIRoot = getStorybookUI({});

// If you are using React Native vanilla and after installation you don't see your app name here, write it manually.
// If you use Expo you should remove this line.
AppRegistry.registerComponent('%APP_NAME%', () => StorybookUIRoot);

export default StorybookUIRoot;
```

Comment: can you try setting `inlineRequires: false` in the metro config

Comment: -> It is giving `console.error : unhandled promise rejection RangeError : maximum call stack size exceeded (native stack depth), js engine:hermes`
-> error will exist in _DEV_ mode

Comment: Ok well it might be the promises issue I will post a potential solution

Comment: If this is still a problem could you include the version of the storybook packages you are using? Like all the addons packages etc

Answer (score 3):

I noticed this error occurs if you are using the `Hermes` engine for whatever reason. If you disable the `Hermes` engine, you should be able to use Storybook. Note that you may want to enable the `Hermes` engine for production though. To enable/disable `Hermes` for ios, it should be in the `Podfile` and for android in `android/app/build.gradle`

Comment: You can use hermes with react native storybook no problem. However sometimes there are issues with the inlineRequires setting for metro. This will hopefully get fixed in the 6.0 release.

Comment: Ok, that is good to know. Thanks Danny. I do see that the project I'm working on has inlineRequires enabled.